# HibernateException: proxy handle is no longer valid after database violation error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have loop to save couple of objects. In loop a call service method and catch exceptions. Service save method is annotated @Transactional and inside does hibernate saveOrUpdate call. 
Service is provided by getBean method of ApplicationContext object. I call it only once before loop.

In the loop, after i catch exception of oracle constraint violation :

> org.hibernate.exception.constraintviolationexception: ora-00001: unique constraint (ccb.sys_c0017085) violated

I log problem and try to save another object. Next exception i get is:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: proxy handle is no longer valid

Sometimes it occurs only one time after each ora error but sometimes it repeats for more objects (iterations).

How to handle this exception & how to make save operation possible?

I'm using
Spring 3.1.3 and Hibernate 4.1.7.

[edit]
Some code sample:

```
@Service
public class ServiceForRecord {
    @Transactional
public Record saveRecord(Record record, String user) {
      Record obj = record;
      // some validation & seting internal values
      getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(obj)
      return obj;
    }
...
```

and in my loop i do:

```
//in params:
serviceClass = ServiceForRecord.class;
entityClass = Record.class;
saveMethod = "saveRecord";
//loop prepare
service = getApplicationContext().getBean(serviceClass);
serviceSave = serviceClass.getMethod("saveRecord", Record.class, String.class);
while (condition) {
entity =  BeanUtils.instantiate(entityClass);
//setup entity
serviceSave.invoke(service, entity, "testUser");
//catch error
} //end while
```

[edit]
Stack trace:

```
PreparedStatementProxyHandler(AbstractProxyHandler).errorIfInvalid() line: 63   
PreparedStatementProxyHandler(AbstractStatementProxyHandler).continueInvocation(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 100 
PreparedStatementProxyHandler(AbstractProxyHandler).invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 81   
$Proxy100.clearBatch() line: not available  
NonBatchingBatch(AbstractBatchImpl).releaseStatements() line: 163   
NonBatchingBatch(AbstractBatchImpl).execute() line: 152 
JdbcCoordinatorImpl.getBatch(BatchKey) line: 151    
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).insert(Serializable, Object[], boolean[], int, String, Object, SessionImplementor) line: 2940   
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).insert(Serializable, Object[], Object, SessionImplementor) line: 3403   
EntityInsertAction.execute() line: 88   
ActionQueue.execute(Executable) line: 362   
ActionQueue.executeActions(List) line: 354  
ActionQueue.executeActions() line: 275  
DefaultFlushEventListener(AbstractFlushingEventListener).performExecutions(EventSource) line: 326   
DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(FlushEvent) line: 52  
SessionImpl.flush() line: 1210  
SessionImpl.managedFlush() line: 399    
JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit() line: 101 
JdbcTransaction(AbstractTransactionImpl).commit() line: 175 
HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 480    
HibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 754   
HibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).commit(TransactionStatus) line: 723 
TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) line: 392    
TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 120   
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 50   
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 202   
$Proxy71.save(Account, String) line: not available  
GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available    
ImportServiceProvider.save(Object, String) line: 380
```

[edit]
last thing i noticed is that it does not occur on MS SQL Server, only on Oracle

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace ? And why are you using reflection ? You can simply call `service.saveRecord(entity,"testUser")`

Comment: I prepare generic solution for save records given from file. service class and entity class is given by param. I'll re-generate error and post it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have different suggestions regarding your issue.

**Suggestion 1** : you are wrongly reusing the same session in all transactions.

To check this : put a breakpoint in `saveRecord` and check that the reference to the `SessionImpl` is different in 2 successive calls.

Honestly, there are few chances this is your problem because your code is running with MS SQL Server. So the only chance for this suggestion to be correct is that the constraints in MS SQL Server are not the same as the constraints in Oracle. Additionally, I think hibernate will throw a more explicit exception in this case.

**Suggestion 2** : you are hitting a bug in hibernate 4

There are a few bug reports in hibernate JIRA in this area. (without your code, it's difficult to say what's your exact situation). There are good chance the behavior you have is linked to one of those bugs:

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7688 (this one is very close to yours, but there some others)

Is there some workarounds to this bug ?

I have few suggestions to try :

**set hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to something above 1** . This workaround was suggested [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7688?focusedCommentId=48400&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-48400) by Michale Wyraz and seems to work.

**Don't use reflection** : not sure it will help, but transaction is handled by aop-proxy, and using reflection may cause to bypass some of the transaction manager code (it shouldn't, but it's an hypothesis to check).

**Change the connection release mode** : all those bugs (in hibernate JIRA) are *more or less* related to JdbcConnection management, so changing the [connection release mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-connection-release) may at somepoint help you to identify the issue. (I don't say that changing it is the solution, if you are really hitting a bug in hibernate: your best choice is probably to wait/contribute for the fix)

**Downgrading to hibernate 3.X** : Once again I don't say it's a solution, but it may indicate that you are really facing a bug in hibernate 4.

**Upgrading to hibernate 4.2+** : As suggested in other answer and regarding *recent* changes in hibernate base code: simply upgrading hibernate may solve the problem.

Comment: Thx for your deep analyzing. I followed the easiest suggestions first, and change connection release mode. It does not help and causes rollback error.  In HHH-7688 description I found workaround and follow it. I changed hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to more than 1. Finally it works! So I assume that I'm affected by the same hibernate error.

Comment: I also solved the issue by setting hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to large than 1.

Comment: I had the same issue with WS 7.0. I've updated the version of all the hibernate dependencies from 4.1.9.Final  to 4.2.20.Final and the exception has disappeared. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I lost hours with similar problem when trying to close Session and unfortunately none of ben75's suggestions worked. This was my environment:

- error message: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: proxy handle is no longer valid ...`
- Hibernate version **4.1.7**
- application server: **IBM WebSphere 7**

so just in the case that someone else stumbles upon this error, solution that worked for me was upgrading to Hibernate 4.2. Required jars are:

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar

HTH.

Comment: Had a similar issue with IBM RAD 755. After upgrading to version 7555 the problem has disappeared. No clue about the reason, I guess it's not related to hibernate version.

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Definitely a very strange error. What are the differences between these two versions?

Comment: honestly I don't know, I have to check. I don't know why I can't set notification with your username, I tried '@MiljenMikic' but didn't work.

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Probably because when you are leaving a comment below someone's response, he/she always receives a notification. I got the notification without mentioning username :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. `@Transactional` closes transaction on Exception by rollback. So objects becomes kind of detached.

I would remove the `@Transactional` from the main method where you iterate the objects to be saved and make @Transactional a separet method which only saves objects.

Comment: I provide some code. I think i do exactly like you suggest, didn't I?

Comment: I mean, that I used it this way before. No success.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate 4.1.3 does not close batched statements if they threw an exception (in org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch()).
You catch the exception, rollback the current transaction, begin a new one and hope that everything is perfect.
But if you run a native update script (for instance), after the run, the finally wants to close the statements. And here it comes, the unclosed (now detached because of the rollback) statement throws this exception and your new transaction goes wrong. Luckily before the new exception the statements get cleared, so only the first update gets wrong...
I created a handler method which I call on every rollback (this case it gets called after the initial exception), and after the rollback and begin I create a dummy (and fast) update (update [tablename] set [column]=[column] where 1=2) and execute it. It triggers the above error, I catch it, rolling back the transaction once again and create a new, so I exit the method with a good hibernate session and a living transaction.
It is an ugly workaround, but I cannot upgrade hibernate version now...